# How to execute an equation with variables from 3 lists and make a list of results?

Tags: list, numpy, variables, math, equations

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import math
from math import *
import random

a_1 = -3.54
a_2 = 0.83
b_1 = 9601.0
b_2 = -2366.0
c_1 = 196.0
c_2 = 32.0  
mpf = 0.6    #maximum packing fraction

temperature=[]
water=[]
crystals=[]
LM = []      #log_melt
MV = []      #melt_visc
MMV = []     #magma visc

output = []                                              

for step in range(0,5):   #randomize variables

    temp_list = np.arange(650,900,5)
    temperature.append(random.choice(temp_list+273))

    water_list=np.arange(0.1,12.2,0.01)
    water.append(random.choice(water_list))

    crystal_list=np.arange(0.05,0.5,0.05)
    crystals.append(random.choice(crystal_list))

print temperature
print water
print crystals

LM.append(a_1+ a_2 * (math.log(water[0])))+(b_1+b_2*(math.log(water[0])))/ ((temperature)-(c_1+c_2*(math.log(water[0]))))
MV.append(10**LM)
MMV.append(MV*(1-crystals/mpf)**(-5/2))

print LM
print MV
print MMV
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more in detail what part isn't working as expected? This is just a junk of code and nobody can say what it should do and what it shouldn't.

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to read. Please format the code properly using the options in the top bar of the text editor. (You can see the preview of your post below that). Also write your question in the body of the text, not in the title and set an accurate title that gives an idea of the question only.

Comment: @Eskapp: I already edited his code formatting. Unfortunately, by now I'm missing just a few points of reputation to make my edit visible without a peer review.